# strip slashes in php linux

Tags: php, fwrite

I want to ask a very simple question.

I am working on a project in which I have entered a code, say I am entering a code like :

```
<?php
echo "Test";
?>
```

On click of a save button, This code is being saved into a php file say `testfile.php`.

When I am running this file on `windows 7 - wamp server`, then this is OK, but When I hosted this file on `000webhost.com` which is `linux server` then some backslashes (\) are added before `" "`. For writing into file, I am using code

```
$code = $_POST['yourcode'];
$openphp = fopen("testfile.php","w");
fwrite($openphp, $code);
fclose($openphp);
```

In Linux server, this code is written as :

```
<?php
echo \"test\";

?>
```

I dont want to save this backslashes (\), how can I avoid this while writing the file

Comment: You're basically letting people inject code (a shell) to root the server ?

Comment: this is magic quotes in action

Comment: How can I remove these magic quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `.htaccess` file in the same folder as your script and add the following

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

Comment: will it be any drawback of this ?

Comment: @lord_linus You should first test it since you're on a shared server (which may not work)

Comment: @lord_linus of course it's a security threat since you're letting users to upload php code in a php file.

Comment: As mentioned on the php.net documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php), magic quotes is deprecated now so you should code without it switched on for future-proofing purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure magic quotes is turned off on your Linux server:

http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

But your script seems pretty dangerous without any escaping or validation checking anyway...

Answer (score 0):

You may configure php.ini for this

```
; Magic quotes
;

; Magic quotes for incoming GET/POST/Cookie data.
magic_quotes_gpc = Off

; Magic quotes for runtime-generated data, e.g. data from SQL, from exec(), etc.
;magic_quotes_runtime = Off

; Use Sybase-style magic quotes (escape ' with '' instead of \').
;magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```

Or in the beginning of your php files you can set it with `ini_set()`

```
ini_set("magic_quotes_gpc", "Off");
```

Comment: Your first solution won't work since he's on a shared server. Your second one won't work since `magic_quotes_gpc` can't be changed with `ini_set`, check this [list](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php)